# Read from stdin, but only while socket is connected

Tags: rust, tcp, stdin

I'm trying to build a simple Rust in-terminal TCP chat program.
I want to read user input from `stdin`, but *only* while the connection is still alive.

Specifically I want to avoid the situation where you send a line only to notice that the connection has been broken.

How can I abort my line read in such a situation?
Ideally I'd print a message and attempt to reconnect, without disrupting whatever the user has been writing so far. At the very least I want to mimic the behaviour of SSH in the way that it tells you that the connection has been lost and aborts the read.

This is as much a conceptual/design question as it is an engineering one.
There are probably a few ways to solve this and I'd appreciate good suggestions on how to do this in an idiomatic way.

Currently I'm just calling this function in a loop, whereupon I transmit whatever I read:

```
fn read_line() -> String {
    let mut input = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
    input.trim().to_string()
}
```

Comment: You can’t detect the dropped connection *until* you try to send over it.

Comment: That is easily be solved by sending regular keepalive packets.